# Compute the spectrum for a operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

> Find the spectrum of the operator 
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> A & \colon C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1] \\ 
>   & f  \mapsto (Af)(x) := f(x) + \int_0^x f(t)dt 
> \end{split}
> $$

P.S.: I know the spectrum of $A_1\colon f  \mapsto \int_0^x f(t)dt$

Answer (score 2):

The spectrum comes from analyzing $A-\lambda I$. Since $A = A_1+I$, you can see that $A-\lambda I = A_1-(\lambda-1)I$. It follows that $\sigma(A) = \sigma(A_1) +\{1\}$.

Comment: $\sigma(A) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace + \lbrace 1 \rbrace = \lbrace 1\rbrace? $

Comment: Yes. A fairly standard notation for sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ is $A\square B = \{a \square b| a\in A, b \in B \}$, where $\square$ is some binary operator such as $+$.